# I was adjusting my mouse speed set it to zero and then saved it. (not on purpose) How do it change it without a mouse

Tags: mouse

The system is an older 32 bit Quad Core Dell .
The OS is 18.04 LTS.
The mouse works fine on the login screen (I also have Unity checked there).
After I log in the system comes up fine but the mouse won't move.
I tried Keyboard shortcuts, but I can't get to anyplace useful.
Tried xinput , but couldn't figure out mouse ID.

Comment: Try `gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse motion-acceleration` and `gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse motion-threshold`.

Comment: got "no such Key" for  both motion-acceleration and motion-threshold......I have "Ubuntu" checked on the login screen not "unity" above.

Comment: @DennisGaskil how did you change it? GUI or CLI??

Comment: Command line ..............Id gsettings fully supported by 18.04 LTS

Comment: Command line ..............Is gsettings fully supported by 18.04 LTS..do we have to use dconf or something else .  I saw on Youtube where they did an APT Uninstall of mouse software , then reinstalled it , I was not sure if the package names would be different in my version , since the Unity to  Gnome changes.